# Flask issue with python: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, flask

New to Flask and API development, but I'm trying to figure out what's wrong here.

This is my code in my koho-flask.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
import new_model_zero_shot as model

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

#create new user_palette object
user = model.user_palette(model.cold_start(), 1)

dish_list = model.dish_list

#user.recommend_meal(['chicken', 'rice'], query_type = ['our_dbs', dish_list], name_csv = None)

# argument parsing
parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('query')

# we already have a way to package the output to user
class GetRecipes(Resource):
    def get(self):
        # use parser and find the user's query
        args = parser.parse_args()
        user_query = args['query']
        
        recs = (user.recommend_meal(user_query, 
                             query_type = ['our_dbs', dish_list], name_csv = None))
        return recs
    
class Hello(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'data': "Hello wassup!"}






#recipe search endpoint
api.add_resource(GetRecipes, '/')
api.add_resource(Hello, '/')
  #%%
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=False)
```

When I run app.run(debug=False), the server starts.

After, I open a test.py file in the same directory and run this.

```
import requests 

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/'
params ={'query': 'chicken'}
response = requests.get(url, params)
a = response.json()
```

My "a" variable returns a dictionary with the value "The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand". This happens whether I test out my dummy "Hello" endpoint or my real "GetRecipes" endpoint.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Do you have any `add_resource` calls to map your resources to URLs?  Flask doesn't know about the names of your functions.

Comment: Yes, right above the if statement in the koho-flask.py file

Comment: I apologize, I didn't scroll down.  However, you have both functions mapped to the root resource.  Surely you wanted `(GetRecipes, '/GetRecipes')` and `(Hello, '/Hello')`?  Or maybe have Hello mapped to the root?

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the Hello function, but the GetRecipes function is still sending the same response